# What is this broken start menu item?

Tags: windows-10

[menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efl3D.png)

[image]

I have this start menu item. But I do not have the associated program on my pc anymore.

I do have this at: `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\AppIconCache\100\C__Programs_PolyMC_polymc_exe` which is a "file"

And when I look for it: [this is what I see in the Resource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAKeU.png)

[image]

Comment: You state, " I do not have the associated program on my pc anymore." Evidently it has not been completely removed, or is still in the Search index. If this bothers you, rebuild indexes.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I did actually rebuild the index.

Comment: @Berend I am wondering where this item is located. It clearly is not on my PC anymore. I've used the everything program, full pc search, searched registry, etc.

Comment: [PolyMC](https://polymc.org/) is "An Open Source Minecraft launcher". Have you been doing Minecraft?

Comment: Try Autoruns (Sysinternals)  and see if you ca delete the entry with Autoruns

Answer (score 0):

This was solved.

Went to restart my PC and entered the CLI that starts you at X:. Deleted the ProgramData\Search folder and the Search package in LocalAppdata.

Comment: You should probably provide more details on what exactly you did